# Concatenating items from one list into multiple separate lists in python

Tags: python-2.7

I am looking for a logic for the below code in order to concatenate words from the 'Words' list into different lists based on conditions:
first word of each line into Salutaion_List;
second word of each line into First-Name_list;
so on..
So that the new words from each iteration has to be concatenate into corresponding lists(no over write)!!!

I tried it with only two lines of text file(2 iterations) when i gave extra line into the text file  the second is geting over written by the new line!!
Can anyone solve my issue!!!

```
iPath= "C:\PythonInputs\Address.txt"
oPath="C:\PythonInputs\Address1.txt"
# declaration of all lists  

with open(path) as f:

    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 0:
            words=line.split('#')
            #for word in words:
            print words
            word_count= len(words) 
            print ('number of words in the above line# %s\n') % word_count
            salutation = words[0:1]
            First_Name = words[1:2]
            Middle_Name = words[2:3]            
            Last_Name = words[2:3]
            Address = words[3:6]
            City = words[-2:-1]
            State = words[-1:]  

    elif i > 0:
        words=line.split('#')            
        print words
        word_count= len(words)
        print ('number of words in the above line# %s\n') % word_count

        salutation2 = words[0:1]
        New_Sal = salutation + salutation2
        print 'salutation: %s' % (",".join(New_Sal))

        First_Name2 = words[1:2]
        New_First_Name = First_Name + First_Name2
        print 'First_Name: %s' % (",".join(New_First_Name))

        Middle_Name2 = words[2:3]
        New_Middle_Name = Middle_Name + Middle_Name2
        print 'Middle_Name: %s' % (",".join(New_Middle_Name))

        Last_Name2 = words[3:4]
        New_Last_Name = Last_Name + Last_Name2
        print 'Last_Name: %s' % (",".join(New_Last_Name))
        Address2 = words[4:6]
        New_Address = Address + Address2
        print 'Address: %s' % (",".join(New_Address))

        City2 = words[-2:-1]
        New_City= City + City2
        print 'City: %s' % (",".join(New_City))

        State2 = words[-1:]
        New_State = State+State2
        print 'State: %s' % (",".join(New_State))
f.close()

**OUTPUT:**
['Mr', 'Name1', 'Name3', 'Address', 'Address1', 'Address2', 'Address3',  
'City', 'State\n']
number of words in the above line# 9

['Mr', 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Address', 'Address1', 'City', 'State\n']
number of words in the above line# 8

salutation: Mr,Mr
First_Name: Name1,Name1
Middle_Name: ,Name2
Last_Name: Name3,Name3
Address: Address,Address1,Address2, Address,Address1
City: City,City
State: State
,State
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line:

```
for i,line in enumerate(f):
```

Do this:

```
firstline = f.readline()
secondsline = f.readline()
```

and adjust the program.

Comment: Its fine, then how about 'n' number of lines, and concatenating new words into the existing list without over write of old words for each iteration (each line)

Comment: Maybe you could do: `lines = list(f)` to get a list of all lines. Have a try.